# Facebook manage_pages issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been trying to Post on the Behalf of My Page. I am the Admin of the App and the Page

I created a Test App with in my App. I used that APP ID and requested manage_pages and publish_actions scope while loging in like that

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  jQuery.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: 'XXXXXXXXX'
    });     
    jQuery('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){ 
        FB.login(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            postToPage();
        }, {scope: 'manage_pages,publish_actions'});


    });
  });
});
```

And below is my postToPage function

```
function postToPage() {
    var page_id = 'XXXXX';
    window.FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
        if(resp.access_token) {
            window.FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                'post',
                { message: "I'm a Page!", access_token: resp.access_token }
                ,function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I logged in fine. I have been asked for the permission and I did get the access token. Then while posting I get this in response

> "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this
>   action"

Since I am the admin of both the Page and APP and I am using the test APP then I am not where I am missing ?. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.3 then from [change log docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

> publish_pages Permission - This new permission is required to publish
>   as a Page. Previously publish_actions was required. People who granted
>   manage_pages and publish_actions before v2.3 have automatically been
>   granted publish_pages. If anyone logs in via v2.3, you'll need to
>   request publish_pages explicitly in addition to manage_pages.